# embedded terminal into desktop with devilspie!

Tags: command-line, devilspie

I tried to embed a terminal to my desktop using devilspie. My problem is the borders of terminal! what can I do?

The screenshot is that;

[image]

This is the start up command

```
gnome-terminal --role=borderless --window-with-profile=DesktopConsole
```

and This is;

```
(if
        (matches (window_name) "DesktopConsole")
        (begin
                (set_workspace 4)
                (below)
                (undecorate)
                (skip_pager)
                (skip_tasklist)
                (wintype "utility")
                (geometry "+0+0")
                (geometry "400x500")
        )
)
```

`DesktopConsole.ds` config file